# modeling binary classification data

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model, apache-spark, java

I am new to Machine learning. While reading SparkMLLib java code, I found Binary_classification [dataset](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/data/mllib/sample_binary_classification_data.txt). But I am not able to understand how this data is modeled and if I want to model same type of data, what I have to do?